# Count items in ArrayList

Tags: android

How can I count the items in an `ArrayList`?

```
ArrayList list1= new ArrayList();
list1.add("a"); 
list1.add("b"); 
list1.add("c"); 
list1.add("d"); 
list1.add("e"); 
...........
result.setMessage(list1.size()); // = 5
...........
```

It does not work. Where is the error?

Comment: Whats the error you get? list1.size() is true for getting count,you shouldt get an error. is the result object null or something?

Comment: it would be helpful if you could specify the error.

Answer (score 10):

Presumably `result` is an `AlertDialog`, if so, then you are calling `result.setMessage(int)` which expects a resource ID. What you want is to cast the size() value (an int) to a String, e.g. `result.setMessage("" + list1.size())`